# Can IMEI be tracked through IP address if cellular never activated on device?

Tags: wifi

Just want to know if an iPad can be tracked via IMEI over IP address if the device is NOT activated on a cellular network. The device is only used on a WiFi network and has never/will never be connected to cellular network.

Comment: Over wifi the traffic  to the internet will be tied to an IP

Comment: Is the cellular radio on? If so, then the IMEI is likely trasmitting.

Comment: Cellular radio button is turned off. So nothing should be trying to ping a service providers server, etc.

Comment: If the radio is off, then nothing is transmitted

Comment: And then the device can successfully be used over WiFi for its longevity, correct?

Comment: By radio, you simply mean the ‘cellular’ option, radio button, on the iPad settings, correct?

Comment: Also, are you referring to tracking by apps, by the network or by both (together or apart)?

Comment: Tracking by network - for instance, will a mobile carrier be able to track location of the device if cellular is turned off.

Comment: Mobile carriers can't see it if it's not transmitting, but apps may be able to leak the IMEI for you.

Answer (score 2):

The IMEI is transmitted only on the GTP open context packet on GRPS (requests, update, etc...), that is in general what is used on 3G/4G and different versions, but basically is there. So if you device don't sent that packets, general is when you use the radio interface, I don't think the IMEI is transmitted in other cases over WiFi devices or even Ethernet.